# local martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

Consider the ito-process: $X(t)= \sigma(t) dW(t)$ for $t \in [0,T]$, where $\sigma$ is a predictable process and $\int_{0}^T \sigma^2 dt <\infty$.

Consider $X^2(t)$:

Appyling Ito's formula to $f(x)=x^2$ yields:$df(X(t))= 2 X(t) \sigma(t) dW(t) +  \sigma^2(t) dt$

How can I see, that $2 X(t) \sigma(t) dW(t) $ is a local martingale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 X_t \sigma(t) \; dW_t$ should be a local martingale because it is a stochatic integral with a martingale as it's integrator.

Comment: But the largest class of integrands are those for which holds: $\int_0^T  H^2 dt <\infty$ for a predictable process $H$. Is this here possible to see?

Comment: You can see that the sde has Lipschtz coefficient over (0,T) so there is a solution and as $\int_0^T h_s dB_s=\int_0^T X_s\sigma(s)dB_s=Z_T$  with $h^2$ in L^2, so $Z_T$ is a local martingale

Comment: The process $X$ is a.s. continuous on $[0,T]$, hence path-wise bounded there: for a.e. sample point $\omega$, $M(\omega):=\sup\{|X(\omega,t)|: 0\le t\le T\}$ is finite. For such an $\omega$, 
$$
\int_0^T [X(\omega,t)\sigma(\omega,t)]^2 dt \le M(\omega)^2\int_0^T\sigma^2(t) dt <\infty.
$$

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Thank you very much:)